# How do I delete a specific dynamic ExpandedObject from a List?

Tags: c#, list

Now I want to delete the `ExpandedObject` from the list`menu_items` where `mi_obj_num` equals 1 without looping through the whole `List`. Is there a way to do so?

```
List<ExpandoObject> menu_items = new List<ExpandoObject>();
dynamic mi = new ExpandoObject();
mi.character = "Hello";
mi.mi_obj_nm = 1;
menu_items.Add(mi);
mi.character = "World";
mi.mi_obj_nm = 2;
menu_items.Add(mi);
```

Answer (score 2):

The best you're going to be able to do is to use `RemoveAll`.  Internally it of course is going to have a loop through the list, that is unavoidable, although you won't need to type out any loops yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to write a loop, use: `menu_items.RemoveAll(eo => eo.mi_obj_nm == 1)`

If you want direct access, use a data structure differnt to `List`, e.g. a `Dictionary` and use the `mi_obj_nm` for a key.

Comment: `RemoveAll` is not a LINQ method.  It's just an instance method of `List`.

Comment: You are right. I tought it to be an extension method. Updated.